# the difference between company and a companion

Tags: differences

In what situation would you use *company* or a *companion* in the following sentences?

> I have a dog and it's my company.
>   I have a dog and it's my companion.

Can I use *company* instead of *companion* in "a traveling companion"? For example: traveling company.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, atsea. When you looked these words up in a dictionary (as I'm sure you did), what did you find? Please tell us what you already know, so that we can help you better.

Comment: "Traveling companion" is a standard idiom, but "traveling company" is unusual. It **might** be used by some cerebrally sere writer stretching for a trope and possibly misunderstood to refer to a metaphorical travel agency or tour guide. So, I'd say that while you can use "traveling company", it'd be better to say & write "traveling companion"if you want to be instantly understood & not considered linguistically strange.

Answer (score 2):

"Companion" is the more natural of the two phrases to use.

"Company" has two relevant [definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/company) in this case.

> I enjoy the company of my dog.  (definition 1a - the companionship of your dog)
>
> My dog is my only company.  (definition 1b - your dog as one of your companions)

The second is closer to your example, but the *only* is an important qualifier because it helps to highlight that you're talking about the dog being one of *many potential companions*.   Just saying "my dog is my company" by itself sounds awkward.

Comment: I should think that "the second is _closer_ to your example" is "proper" English.

Comment: @BillFranke - Indeed, thank you.  (You could have just edited it :))

Comment: @BillFranke: He could very well say *the Company:)*.

Comment: @Lynn: Sometimes that kind of editing is presumptuous, but it's been done to a couple of my posted answers. Many high-level native speakers don't see anything wrong with sentences like "Alpha is the oldest twin and Beta, the youngest". Who am I to insist that everyone else think & express themselves as I do? Only **peacocks** put themselves in that position.

Comment: @BillFranke:When I say 'My dog is my company', does it mean it is right with me now, but not necessarily mean it's my companion? When I say 'my dog is my companion', does it mean that it might not be with me right now, but I spend a lot of time with it? Thank you all your comments.

Comment: @atsea: Context decides what it means. There's no inherent implication that the dog is or isn't with you at the moment you say 'My dog is my company', only if you say 'My dog is my constant companion'. Some people talk to beings who aren't there. The Tom Hanks character in the movie about the FedEx guy stranded on an island for >7 years had one companion: Wilson, the soccer ball. A companion accompanies you, goes with you, is with you when you're together, & may be your only "company", even when not with you. Chang & Eng were constant companions but maybe not always "company" for each other.

Comment: @BillFranke:"Some people talk to beings who aren't there." Could you please give an example of the quote you said?

Comment: Many children have imaginary friends they talk to. My current wife is going to adopt my minor son from my previous marriage, and she was told by her parents that she had to go to the temple where my late wife's ashes are kept and "tell her" about the adoption and that my son is planning to change all the characters in his Chinese name. The Tom Hanks character has conversations with a soccer ball as if the ball were able to hear and understand English. There are other examples.

Comment: @BillFranke:Thanks very much for your reply. Is the soccer ball Tom Hanks's companion and company in the movie? Do the two words mean the same thing here?

Comment: @atsea: Yes, it is while Hanks' character is on the island. The soccer ball is his only company and his only companion.

Comment: @atsea - I would add to what Bill said, though, that "the ball was his company" still doesn't sound right.    "the ball was his *only* company" is what you would say.

Comment: @Lynn:Thanks for your correction. If I have two dogs and they are my companions, should I say 'my dogs are my only company' or ...my company? Can I use 'a companion' instead of 'company' in this sentence from dictionary "Bessie was glad to have the dog as company."?

Comment: @atsea -  "My dogs are my only company", "My dogs are my companions", "Bessie was glad to have the dog as a companion", and "I was glad to have the dog as company" are all legitimate.   But "my company" just doesn't sound right.  I'm not sure of the grammatical reason *why* it doesn't sound right, but it doesn't :)

Comment: @BillFranke:Can I use either of them without changing the meaning in the example? If I have a friend who asks me to help her to look after her child while she is away for some time. In this case, can I say "I was glad to have the child as a companion/ as company"? What's the difference if there is any? Thanks.

Comment: @atsea: You can say either one & both will be understood to mean the same thing, especially if the child is old enough to talk to you & to willingly go with you to various places. "Company" is to me someone who's there with you but not necessarily by choice (passively present, like an cellmate in prison); a "companion" is to me someone who's with you by choice (actively present). This difference may be idiosyncratic & apply only to me, though.

Comment: @BillFranke:Don't We use a companion for an cellmate in prison? Thank you very much.

Comment: @atsea: Unless my cellmate chose to accompany me to prison and live in my cell with me, I'd just call him _my cellmate_ and not use either one of these words. He may be _company_ because he's there, but he's not there _to keep me company_. He also may be **unwanted company**, like the cockroaches, flies, & mosquitoes in the prison cell. He could be my _antagonist_ or my _enemy_.

Comment: @BillFranke:What's the difference between a companion and a constant companion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @atsea: A constant companion is someone who never leaves you. [Chang & Eng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang_and_Eng_Bunker) were Siamese twins (the politically correct term these days is "conjoined twins") joined at the sternum and never separated. They lived that way for more than 62 years. They both married and had children (10 for one and 11 for the other). Their wives could be alone, but they, constant companions, could not.

Comment: @BillFranke: I got this sentence from an online dictionary:"For ten years he had been her constant companion." Does this mean they were always together wherever they were for ten years? Thanks

Comment: @atsea: Because they weren't conjoined twins, they undoubtedly were alone at times during those 10 years: going to the toilet, bathing (perhaps), getting dressed and undressed, doing other things best done alone. It probably means they were _almost always_ together, & even, perhaps, together every day, but without more information, it's impossible to know exactly what . Every word & every expression has a specific context. With Chang & Eng, constant meant 24 hours a day, 7 days a week from birth until death. For non-conjoined constant companions, it's usually not that suffocatingly intense.

Comment: @BillFranke: What's the difference in meaning between 'My dog is my only company' and 'my dog is my companion'? Does 'My dog is my only company' mean my dog is my only companion? Thanks.

Comment: @atsea: If by now you cannot figure out the difference, there seems to me to be no point in discussing it any further. This conversation is now over and done with.

Answer (score 0):

"Company" is uncountable, while "companion" is countable. You can think of them as words similar to "agriculture" and "farm". When you refer to a plurality of company, you need to use a measure word. "I have five people in my company". "My company is five people". Companions are individual entities. You do not need to use a measure word. You can even use them together, "I have five companions in my company". "Company" is an abstract concept; a companion is a distinct noun.

Comment: I think you mean uncountable vs. countable with "indiscreet" vs. "discreet" (both of which are the wrong word entirely: you were probably thinking of *discrete*, which doesn't have an antonym in *in-*). I have no clue what you mean by "measure word", however.

Comment: I think you are on the right track, Ari, but: 1) ‘company’ and ‘companion’ are both ‘discrete’ words, referring to ‘indiscrete’ and ‘discrete’ entities, respectively. 2) I think you are confusing two concepts: *company* is a countable ‘collective’ noun, designating a collection of individuals, not an uncountable ‘mass’ noun like *humanity*, which has no discrete subsets. 3) It is such ‘mass’ nouns which can be said to name ‘abstract concepts’; *company* names a group, and *companion* an individual; but all three are ‘distinct nouns’, because each is distinct from all other nouns.

Comment: @S: "Company" is also an abstraction on the level of "freedom" and "democracy", semantically empty concepts that vary in meaning by context & user. Some folks find insects, flowers, other linguistically incapable life forms "company"; others find it in imaginary companions. There's a distinct difference in desiring "company" (the abstraction) & "a company" (the CIA or some aggregation of corporate employees). As a mass, non-count noun, "company" has no discrete subsets when used to mean "Some beings to make my life less lonely". "Humanity" & "company" are different types of Platonic forms.

Comment: "Humanity" in the concrete consists only of one or more sets of humans, but "company" can consist of a variety of sets of different types of ethereal, imaginary, animate or inanimate beings or objects (stuffed tigers like Hobbes, eg). I'm sure there's more to say about this, but I can't think of it now.

Comment: @BillFranke  You are quite right, and I wrote too hastily. My aplologies to *the* company.